# AWS Cognito Facebook login User details not refreshed on identity browser iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Hi am working on AWS Cognito Facebook and GooglePlus Login for iOS. In the older SDK they have used the below code for refreshing user,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *merge = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.credentialsProvider.logins];
   [merge addEntriesFromDictionary:logins]         
   self.credentialsProvider.logins = merge;
   // Force a refresh of credentials to see if we need to merge
   task = [self.credentialsProvider refresh];
```

The above part works fine. Can you please let me know how to refresh user credential provider in the new SDK. I tried using the below code but user is not getting refreshed in identity browser.

```
-(void)completeLogin {

    AWSTask *task;
    if (self.credentialsProvider == nil) {
        task = [self initializeClients];
    }
    else {

        [[self.credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
            if (task.error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
            } else {
                // the task result will contain the identity id
                NSString *cognitoId = task.result;
                NSLog(@"cognitoId : %@",cognitoId);
            }
            return [[self.credentialsProvider credentials] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCredentials *> * _Nonnull task) {
                NSLog(@"credentials task.result: %@", task.result);
                return nil;
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved this by using,                                          
       [self.identityProviderManager mergeLogins:logins];
        [self.credentialsProvider invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials];
        task = [self.credentialsProvider getIdentityId];
        task = [self.credentialsProvider credentials];